# Select HTML node by attribute with dommy

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation, clojurescript

Using [dommy](https://github.com/Prismatic/dommy) in ClojureScript, how do you make a node selection by attribute? For example, in jQuery this would look like `$('tr[data-id=1]')`. I tried `(sel1 "tr[data-id=1]")` but I got this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute query: 'tr[data-id=1]' is not a valid selector.

Is this possible with dommy? If not, what's the best alternative in ClojureScript? jayq?

Sample HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr data-id="1">
    <td>Cow</td>
    <td>Moo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post your html part here ?

Comment: @KrishR Sample HTML added.

Comment: If you’ve got answer for your question it’s always kind to mark the right one, even if it’s yours ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dommy uses `document.querySelectorAll` under the hood, which requires the attribute's value in the selector to be in quotes.

```
(sel1 "tr[data-id='1']")
```

If you don't want to use quotes, there are at least two simple alternatives:

**goog.dom.query** is already available as a dependency in ClojureScript and it supports attribute selection.

```
(ns example
  (:require [goog.dom.query :as query]))

(query "tr[data-id=1]")
```

[**jayq**](https://github.com/ibdknox/jayq) is a wrapper for jQuery. Add `[jayq "2.5.0"]` to your `project.clj` to use it.

```
(ns example
  (:require [jayq.core :refer [$]]))

($ "tr[data-id=1]")
```

(Thanks to yonki for pointing out the quotes are necessary.)

Answer (score 3):

Chill out guys, it’s possible easily. Check this code:

`(sel1 "tr[data-id=\"1\"]")`

Have a look at your HTML code `<tr data-id="1">`. You see that `data-id` value is in quotation marks. You just have to include quotation marks in your selector and everything gonna be ok. `\"` is escaped quotation marks. Hope that’s fairly understandable.

Lastly: Dommy uses `querySelectorAll` when needed, so you can use every CSS selector that browser is capabale of recognizing.

Comment: You are right. `querySelectorAll` requires the attribute value to be in quotes, which is why it doesn't work otherwise. Other libraries are more lenient in how they parse the selector, which is nice. (BTW, you can use single quotes in the selector in order to avoid having to escape double quotes: `(sel1 "tr[data-id='1']")`.)

Answer (score 0):

this approach can work also!

```
(ns dosync2.core
  (:require [dommy.utils :as utils]
            [dommy.core :as dommy]
            [dommy.attrs :as dattr])
  (:use-macros
    [dommy.macros :only [node sel sel1]]))

(defn select-by-tag-and-attr-value [the-tag the-attr the-attr-value]
  (let [tag-selection (sel the-tag)]
    (filter #(= the-attr-value (dattr/attr % the-attr)) tag-selection)
    )
  )

(. js/console (log (clj->js (select-by-tag-and-attr-value :tr :data-id 1))))
```